# WordPress-ERROR: "Table Prefix" must not be empty

Tags: html, css, wordpress, xampp

I am installing WordPress.In the 1st step of installation process it required database details. I have entered all. I am using xampp and I have tables in db named as `wordpress_tbl_table1,wordpress_tbl_table2.`..So in the table prefix field I entered wordpress_tbl_ , but it is giving error

> ERROR: "Table Prefix" must not be empty.

In wp-config-sample file,it is as `$table_prefix  = 'wordpress_tbl_';`
after googling I found solution to copy wp-config file, I have 'wp-config-sample' file. If I copy or rename this it gives error that needs 'wp-config-sample' file.
Am I making any mistake in table-prefix field?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check following thing database.

**Step 1 : Check Option table**

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_a123456_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE '%wp_%
```

**Step 2 : Check usermeta table**

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_a123456_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%wp_%'
```

**Check Step to install Fresh Wordpress**

- Open htdocs and extract wordpress.zip here.
- Create blank database and copy name of database.
- Run you project.
- There is page select lanaguae.
- fill required inforamtion

That's it.install complete.

**Download Wordpress** https://wordpress.org/download/

**Blank Screen while install**

go to path `xampp\php\php.ini` open it and edit max_execution_time to

```
max_execution_time = 90
```

**Note : Please reinstall xampp if still haveing issue**

Answer (score 0):

## 1) you should have asked at [`wordpress.stackexchange.com`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

**2)**: No, you should create an empty database from `phpmyadmin`, name it i.e. `mywp` and when installing WP, enter any table prefix you want in that field.